# On refresh, values keep adding in drop down

Tags: php

Code:

```
public function getEmployeeId() {
        if (!isset($_SESSION["email"]) || !isset($_SESSION["passwrd"])) {
            header("Location:index.php");
            // Cannot Access this page without Login.
        }


            $_SESSION['ids'][] = "";
            $query = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT EmployeeId from employees where EmployeeId NOT IN(Select EmployeeId from employeeprofile)") or die("Query execution failed: " . mysqli_error());
            while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                // Push the id to the array.
                $_SESSION['ids'][] = $row["EmployeeId"];
            }


    }
```

Values are coming from database and whenever I refresh duplicate values are added. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because every time you refresh the page, (probably with every `getEmployeeId()` method call) SQL query gets executed and employee ids gets appended to `$_SESSION['ids']` array. You need to encapsulate *that* block of code inside an `if` block.

```
public function getEmployeeId() {
    if (!isset($_SESSION["email"]) || !isset($_SESSION["passwrd"])) {
        header("Location:index.php");
        exit();
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['ids']) && count($_SESSION['ids']) == 0){
        $_SESSION['ids'][] = "";
        $query = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT EmployeeId from employees where EmployeeId NOT IN(Select EmployeeId from employeeprofile)") or die("Query execution failed: " . mysqli_error());
        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            $_SESSION['ids'][] = $row["EmployeeId"];
        }   
    }
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** You need to add `exit();` after `header(...);` statement, because `header(...);` alone itself is not sufficient to redirect the user to a different page.

Comment: what is $_SESSION['id']

Comment: @abby That one should be `$_SESSION['ids']`, I've updated my answer. Please test your application with the updated code snippet.

Comment: You're missing an `exit()` after the `header()`, Rajdeep. This will set up a race condition in which the PHP execution will carry on until the connection is terminated by the client side, rarely what you would want. Would you edit the answer?

Comment: @halfer Yeah, you're right. I've added that one as well. Since OP didn't mention any issue with page redirection, so somehow *that* code block had been overlooked. Thanks for pointing this out. :-)

Comment: Thanks Rajdeep. @abby: see notes above.